# gcc class usage

Tags: class, gcc, syntax-error, keyword

How to use classes in c++ when compiling with gcc?

I use:

```
#pragma once

#include "cv.h"

class ImagesData {
public:
    IplImage* frameImage;

    ImagesData(){};

    int Init()
    {
    }

    ~ImagesData()
    {
    };
};
```

and get errors: syntax error before 'ImagesData', syntax error before '{' token

Comment: Please post the command line you use to invoke GCC. Also, what is the filename extension of your source file?

Answer (score 1):

You use classes when compiling with GCC the same way as with any other C++ compiler: Write correct C++ code, and you won't get compiler errors.

1. `#pragma once` is a *non-standard* extension. Use standard include guards - proper preprocessors handle them just as efficiently as `#pragma once`.
2. Remember to invoke GCC as `g++` when trying to compile C++ code. `gcc` is a *C* compiler.

Comment: `#pragma once` is available on MSVC, GCC, Clang, etc... It's not a MS extension anymore, not for a long time...

Comment: @rubenvb: It is still a *non-standard* and *unnecessary* extension to the language, the use of which is essentially non-portable (as anything that follows after `#pragma`).

Comment: Calling it a Microsoft extension is kinda funny: GCC got it in 1989, Visual C++ got it in 1995/1996. And, uhm, it's probably far more portable than vast majority of the code in the wild, mind you :)

Comment: @Fanael: *sigh*... so I didn't research the origin of `#pragma once` as well as I ought. *Mea culpa.* It's something that I frequently encounter in MSVC sources, next to never encounter in Unix sources, something that's not covered by any standard and something that is *trivially* replaced with a *fully* standard-compliant approach. It has *no* advantage over the standard-compliant approach, and several drawbacks, so I strongly discourage its use, *especially* on an educational website like this.

Comment: Just a nitpick: you're almost right. It has one, single, _tiny_, most probably _completely insignificant_ advantage over The Holy Preprocessor Trinity. It doesn't take an identifier.

Comment: Yep. You know that several GNU software titles actually check if `_STDIO_H` is defined? ;-) (Which, of course, is a bug right there.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `#pragma once`, as [DevSolar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60281/devsolar) pointed out, use the portable include guards, in case you don't know what they are, this is an example:

```
#ifndef _MY_HEADER_H_
#define _MY_HEADER_H_

{ code here }

#endif //_MY_HEADER_H_
```

This will get the same results you are expecting with `#pragma once`

And, as [DevSolar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60281/devsolar) also pointed out, compile with `g++`, *NOT* `gcc`.

Comment: Please note that names starting with a leading underscore (or containing a double underscore) are considered reserved names as per the standard. Even though remote, there is a chance that your `#define _...` might collide with a predefined name.